# Is there anyway to choose specific parts in strnig but ignore others?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to take only expressions like 'A==1' or 'D1 >= 2' from a string (including spaces).
For example:
From - '(A == 3 AND B == 4) OR ( A==1 AND B==2)'
I expect to get: [A == 3, B == 4, A==1, B==2].
Here's my code:

```js
let myString = '(A == 3 AND B == 4) OR ( A==1 AND B==2)';
const result = myString.match(/[a-z0-9\s]+(>|<|==|>=|<=|!=|\s)\d/gi);  
console.log(result); //result => [A == 3 ,AND B == 4,A==1 ,AND B==2]
```

I want my regex to take only the specific pattern of {param}{operator}{param} but with blank spaces.
I tried many ways, but none was successful.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You might write the pattern with the case insensitive flag as:

```
\b[a-z0-9]+\s*(?:[=!]=|[<>]=?)\s*\d+\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ chars a-z or a digit 0-9
- `\s*` Match optional whitspace cahrs
- `(?:[=!]=|[<>]=?)` Match either `=!` `==` `<` `>` `<=` `>=`
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `\d+\b` 1+ digits and a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cz4WHw/1)

For only leading uppercase chars:

```
\b[A-Z]+\s*(?:[=!]=|[<>]=?)\s*\d+\b
```

```js
const regex = /\b[A-Z]+\s*(?:[=!]=|[<>]=?)\s*\d+\b/g;
const s = `(A == 3 AND B == 4) OR ( A==1 AND B==2)`;
console.log(s.match(regex))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OZu9vn/1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
[a-z\d]+\s*[=<>!]+\s*[a-z\d]
```

Explanation:

- `[a-z\d]+\s*` - left side of comparison
- `[=<>!]+` - comparison operators
- `\s*[a-z\d]` - right side of comparison

```js
let myString = '(A == 3 AND B == 4) OR ( A==1 AND B==2)';

const result = myString.match(/[a-z\d]+\s*[=<>!]+\s*[a-z\d]/gi);

console.log(result);
```